# How do I Make A Function?

Tags: c++

My function doesn't seem to be working no matter what I do (with different errors). How do I solve this? I know I can just put everything in int main, but it is a requirement for me to put in a function.

EDIT: The function is supposed to output some patterns based on a number that the user inputs. The error message is either(too many arguments for the function) (too few arguments) or (s1 is undeclared)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void cpppatterns(int number, int s1, int s2, int hs1, int hs2, int hs3, int cb1, int cb2, int d1, int d2, int d3, int d4, int d5, int sv1, int sv2, int sh1, int sh2, int sd1, int sd2, int sdur1, int sdur2, int sdLL1, int sdLL2, int sdLr1, int sdLr2, int TUL1, int TUL2, int TUR1, int TUR2, int TURS, int TLL1, int TLL2, int TLR1, int  TLR2, int TLRS, int lb1)
{

//square

cout << endl << "SQUARE:" << endl;
for (s1 = 0; s1 < number; s1++){
    s2 = 0;
    cout << "   ";
    do {
        cout << "*";
        s2++;
    } while (s2 < number);
    cout << endl;
}

// hollow square :

cout << endl << "HOLLOW SQUARE:" << endl;
for (hs1 = 0; hs1 < number; hs1++){
    hs2 = 0;
    hs3 = 0;
    cout << "   ";
    if (hs1 == 0 || hs1 == number - 1){
        do {
            cout << "*";
            hs2++;
        } while (hs2 < number);
    }
    else {
        do {
            if (hs3 == number - 1 || hs3 == 0){
                cout << "*";
            }
            else {
                cout << " ";
            }
            hs3++;
        } while (hs3 < number);
    }
    cout << endl;
}


// checker-board :

cout << endl << "CHECKER-BOARD:" << endl;
for (cb1 = 0; cb1 < number; cb1++){
    cb2 = 0;
    cout << "   ";
    do {
        if (cb1 % 2 == 0){
            if (cb2 % 2 == 0){
                cout << "*";
            }
            else{
                cout << " ";
            }
        }
        else{
            if (cb2 % 2 != 0){
                cout << "*";
            }
            else{
                cout << " ";
            }
        }
        cb2++;
    } while (cb2 < number);
    cout << endl;
}

//diamond:

cout << endl << "DIAMOND:" << endl;
d2 = number;
d4 = 1;

for (d1 = 1; d1 <= number; d1++){
    cout << "   ";
    d3 = 0;
    d5 = 0;
    do {
        cout << " ";
        d3++;
    } while (d3 < d2);
    do {
        cout << "*";
        d5++;
    } while (d5 < d4);
    d4++; d4++;
    d2--;
    cout << endl;
}
d2 = 1;
d4 = d4 - 4;
for (d1 = 1; d1 < number; d1++){
    cout << "   ";
    d2++;
    d3 = 0;
    d5 = 0;
    do {
        cout << " ";
        d3++;
    } while (d3 < d2);
    do {
        cout << "*";
        d5++;
    } while (d5 < d4);
    d4--; d4--;
    cout << endl;
}

// same # vertically

cout << endl << "SAME #S VERTICALLY:" << endl;
for (int sv1 = 1; sv1 <= number; sv1++) {
    cout << "   ";
    for (int sv2 = 1; sv2 <= number; sv2++){
        cout << sv2;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// same # horizontally 

cout << endl << "SAME #S HORIZONTALLY:" << endl;
for (int sh1 = 1; sh1 <= number; sh1++) {
    cout << "   ";
    for (int sh2 = 1; sh2 <= number; sh2++){
        cout << sh1;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
// same # DIAGONALLY ul


cout << endl << "SAME #S DIAGONALLY UPPER LEFT:" << endl;
for (int sd1 = 1; sd1 <= number; sd1++) {
    cout << "   ";
    for (int sd2 = sd1; sd2 < number + sd1; sd2++){
        cout << sd2;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// same # DIAGONALLY UR

cout << endl << "SAME #S DIAGONALLY UPPER RIGHT:" << endl;
for (int sdur1 = 1; sdur1 <= number; sdur1++) {
    sdur2 = number - 1 + sdur1;
    cout << "   ";
    for (; sdur2 >= sdur1; sdur2--){
        cout << sdur2;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// same # DIAGONALLY LL

cout << endl << "SAME #S DIAGONALLY LOWER LEFT:" << endl;
for (int sdLL1 = 1; sdLL1 <= number; sdLL1++) {
    cout << "   ";
    for (sdLL2 = number + 1 - sdLL1; sdLL2 <= 2 * number - sdLL1; sdLL2++){
        cout << sdLL2;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// same # DIAGONALLY LR

cout << endl << "SAME #S DIAGONALLY LOWER RIGHT:" << endl;
for (int sdLr1 = 1; sdLr1 <= number; sdLr1++) {
    cout << "   ";
    for (sdLr2 = 2 * number - sdLr1; sdLr2 >= 1 + number - sdLr1; sdLr2--){
        cout << sdLr2;
    }
    cout << endl;
}


// triangle ul

cout << endl << "TRIANGLE, STARTING IN UPPER LEFT:" << endl;
for (int TUL1 = 1; TUL1 <= number; TUL1++) {
    cout << "   ";
    for (TUL2 = TUL1; TUL2 <= number; TUL2++){
        cout << TUL2;
    }
    cout << endl;
}


// triangle uR

cout << endl << "TRIANGLE, STARTING IN UPPER RIGHT:" << endl;
for (int TUR1 = 1; TUR1 <= number; TUR1++) {
    cout << "   ";
    for (TURS = 0; TURS < TUR1 - 1; TURS++){
        cout << " ";
    }
    for (TUR2 = number; TUR2 >= TUR1; TUR2--){
        cout << TUR2;
    }
    cout << endl;
}


// triangle LL

cout << endl << "TRIANGLE, STARTING IN LOWER LEFT:" << endl;
for (int TLL1 = 1; TLL1 <= number; TLL1++) {
    cout << "   ";
    for (TLL2 = number + 1 - TLL1; TLL2 <= number; TLL2++){
        cout << TLL2;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// triangle LR

cout << endl << "TRIANGLE, STARTING IN LOWER RIGHT:" << endl;
for (int TLR1 = 1; TLR1 <= number; TLR1++) {
    cout << "   ";
    for (TLRS = 0; TLRS < number - TLR1; TLRS++){
        cout << " ";
    }
    for (TLR2 = number; TLR2 >= number + 1 - TLR1; TLR2--){
        cout << TLR2;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// letter box: 

int lb2 = 'A';
cout << endl << "LETTER BOX:" << endl;
lb1 = number + 64;
for (lb2 = 0; lb2 <= number; lb2++) {
    cout << lb2;
}



}

int main() {
    int number, s1, s2, hs1, hs2, hs3, cb1, cb2, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, sv1, sv2, sh1, sh2, sd1, sd2, sdur1, sdur2, sdLL1, sdLL2, sdLr1, sdLr2, TUL1, TUL2, TUR1, TUR2, TURS, TLL1, TLL2, TLR1, TLR2, TLRS, lb1;
cin >> number;
cpppatterns(number, s1, s2, hs1, hs2, hs3, cb1, cb2, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, sv1, sv2, sh1, sh2, sd1, sd2, sdur1, sdur2, sdLL1, sdLL2, sdLr1, sdLr2, TUL1, TUL2, TUR1, TUR2, TURS, TLL1, TLL2, TLR1, TLR2, TLRS, lb1);

// factors:
int i;
cout << "Factors of " << number << " are: " << endl;
for (i = 1; i <= number; ++i)
{
    if (number%i == 0)
        cout << i << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Too much code. No explanation of what the function is supposed to do. No explanation what the problem is.

Comment: @RSahu : Ok, I fixed it

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should document exactly what all those parameters are..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only declare `number` in main, and have this argument only in your function. Move the the declaration for the rest of the variables inside the function. Better yet, split the function into multiple independent functions.